# Contar +1 sempre que condicional for verdadeira

Tags: javascript

É possível usar um contador em uma condicional?

```
if(variavel tal === "AAB"){
    var count = 0;
        function contador(){
            cont++;
}
document.getElementById('boxg').innerHTML = count;
}


<div id='boxg'></div>
```

Fiz assim, mas só mostra 0.

Comment: O que seria um "contador em uma condicional"? Condicionais são apenas para executar o código se a condição for verdadeira, não vai ficar se repetindo a não ser que você use um bloco de repetição devida.

Comment: Minha intenção é que quando a condição for verdadeira some +1 na div boxg.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Você precisa declarar sua variável fora do if statement, caso contrário o valor da mesma será sempre alterado de volta pra 0 quando entrar nessa mesma condição.

Outro erro que consigo ver é que sua função **contador** está sendo declarada dentro do if statement, o correto seria declarar essa função fora desse escopo juntamente com a variável **count**.

Detalhe: Dentro da condição você precisa chamar a função e não declará-la.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda! 
Fiz assim e está funcionando, porém não sei se é o correto. 

`if(variavel tal === "AAB"){
    var contador = count++;
  document.getElementById("boxg").innerHTML = contador;
}


var count = 0;
<div id='boxg'></div>`

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Sua pergunta está bem vaga...
O que irá controlar sua variável contadora? Um loop? Um botão setando alguma coisa?...

O mais certo de se implementar contadores é declarando a variável fora do escopo do if (caso a lógica de controle não seja interna à ele) e do loop, para que a cada repetição ela possa ser iterada.

A declaração de função é desnecessária, você poderia resumir seu código à isso levando em consideração que vc use um loop:

```js
let count = 0;

while (condicaoDeParada) {
  if (tal === "AAB") count++;
}

document.getElementById('boxg').innerHTML = count;
```

Answer (score -1):

Veja esse exemplo que fiz incrementando +1 sempre que clicar no botão, acredito que mostre o que deseja que é aumentar o contador e atualizar o valor da div.

```
<div id='boxg'>0</div>
<button id='somar'>Somar</button>

let box = document.getElementById('boxg');
let contador = 0;
let botao = document.getElementById('somar');

botao.onclick = function() {//ativa a função ao clicar no botão
  if(box) { //aqui você faz o seu if
    contar();
    box.innerHTML = contador;
  }

  function contar() {
    contador++;
  }
};
```